# Excel Ref-Error when using Large-If-Array function

Tags: excel

I have worked with array-functions for "large"-functions in excel before to include conditions.

Here is the function I am currently trying to use:

```
{=LARGE(IF($I$21:$I$9666=AC$19;$E$21:$E$9666);1)}
```

The evaluation returns a "#Ref"-error and I cannot figure out why. Columns I and AC include strings and I have checked whether on an individual basis I=AC returns true, which is the case. In column E, I have the numbers to be evaluated in the large-function.

Can anyone help me out here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: And there are no #REF! errors anywhere within those two columns of data?

Comment: Use F5, Special, Formulas, Errors (only), OK to quickly locate formulas returning a #REF! or any other error on your worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula looks OK to me - if there were no qualifying rows you would get `#NUM!` error so if you get `#REF!` error that probably means there are `#REF!` errors somewhere in `E21:E9666` or `I21:I9666`

Either get rid of those errors or if you have `Excel 2010` or a later version try using `AGGREGATE` function which can ignore errors and get the same result, i.e.

`=AGGREGATE(14;6;$E$21:$E$9666/($I$21:$I$9666=AC$19);1)`

`14` signifies `LARGE` function and `6` means ignore errors - see `AGGREGATE` function help for more details

In earlier Excel versions you can use another `IF` function to filter out any errors, i.e.

`=LARGE(IF(ISERROR($I$21:$I$9666&$E$21:$E$966);"";IF($I$21:$I$9666=AC$19;$E$21:$E$9666));1)`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>